# org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException issue with using list()

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

The following query throws the exception:

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("from Associate as a order by a.username asc");
 associates = query.list();
```

> org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [ca.mypkg.model.Associate#0]

If I create an entry in the database with `id` of `0` it works just fine. I don't really get it because I'm just trying to load all the entries in the db not just a specific one.

Similar questions I've found have been concerned with trying to load an object with a given `ID` I'm doing no such thing.

Associate class:

```
@Table(name = "user")
@XmlRootElement(name = "associate")
public class Associate implements Serializable {

private String username;
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String userType;
private int id;
private String email;
private String isActive;
private Department dept;
private String lastUpdated;
private String associate_type;
// ...
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "dept")
public Department getDept() {
    return dept;
}
```

Comment: Looks like problem with the `order by` clause, please post your `Assiociate` `Entity`.

Comment: Looks you don't have the username attribute in the Associate entity class.  As @Atropo mentioned, please provide this class.

Comment: the same exception is thrown even without the order by clause

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my experience this type of error message usually means it does not find joined entity by mentioned id, and not the entity requested in the query (Associate, in your case). 
My guess is that Associate class contains a join entity which has primitive type primary key.

Comment: You're exactly right. It seems in the department table the department manager user id was set to 0 which doesn't exist in the user table. The exception is a bit misleading. THanks